# CountIf not counting values derived from formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I couldn't find a matching answer already but happy to be redirected!

My issue is with `countifs` across two worksheets but I can replicate it in a smaller environment.

I have three columns of data (A-C): -

[image: Picture of data]

Column D has the formula `=IF(A2="Closed",C2-B2,0)`.

That bit works, I now need to count how many took *X* number of days to close: -

[image: Count]

Column G has the formula `=COUNTIFS(A2:A11,"Closed",D2:D11,F2)`

Looking at the pictures `41` and `49` should have a count of 1 right? What have I done wrong? All cells are formated as numbers.

Comment: Check you output in Column D. It must be having decimals. If that is the case, you need to round them using ROUND formula.

Comment: @NiteshHalai That was the answer, could you write it up and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you output in Column D. It must be having decimals. If that is the case, you need to round the formulas in column D using ROUND formula.

```
=ROUND(IF(A2="Closed",C2-B2,0),0)
```

Comment: That was it. Like you say it was taking a date with a time value (which is held in the decimal places) leaving me with with 1.1234 (for example) so it was not matching to 1, I could have done upper and lower but choose to round it. In fact, I actually went with `TRUNC` so not to get rounding up issues.

Answer (score 5):

Your formula in column G uses an absolute comparison to the value in column F.

The problem is that none of your values exactly match that value.

The duration column is formatted to show a value rounded to a day, but the underlying value is not the same as what is showing in the formatted cell.

Therefore, the formula in column G needs to factor in a range of values like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,"Closed",$D$2:$D$11,">="&F2,$D$2:$D$11,"<"&F3)
```

In words: count all the cells where column A shows "Closed" and where the value in column D is between the value in F2 and the value in F3.

You will need to add an extra value in column F for anything above your biggest number in column F.

Answer (score 0):

Rows 4 and 7 have status as "Open" and hence won't be counted by Countifs, i. e. change value of cells A4 and A7 to "Closed" to see updated results.

Also, fix your range $A$2:$A$11, etc. when using Countifs